# How Should I Handle permissions in a Rest API

Tags: api, rest, .net-core, identityserver4, claims

Lets say I have an API with a bunch of Teams. Connected to those teams are users and other resources for example Schedules.
In the database we have two users.

- User 1 which is a member of team 1 and 3
- User 2 which is a member of team 2

How would you handle the permissions to make sure only user 1 can access the resources for team 1 and 3 and not team 2?
It feels like a bad idea to query the database every time a user wants to access a team resource and check if it's allowed to do so, right? There must be a better way of doing things.

My first thought was to put all the Teams that the User is a member of within a Claim inside the token. 
That way I could just read the token, check if the claim for the specific Team is present, if it is, it means that the user is allowed to access the resource.
But I recently read that this is not what Claims are intended for.

Comment: The source doesn't have to be a database. You can also store the information in a configuration file, as shown with the [local PolicyServer](https://github.com/policyserver/policyserver.local). It all depends on how you want to manage the information and where you need it. Having permissions (user authorization) in an access token, is even worse. Take a look at the [Policy Server](https://policyserver.io/) website for some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It feels like a bad idea to query the database every time a user wants to access a team resource and check if it's allowed to do so, right? There must be a better way of doing things.

If you are worried about the amount of queries you are doing on your database, use a cache.

Before you do, I would still first recommend that you quantity 'too many times'. We do a ton of queries, and optimize if and when there's an objective reason to.